# Eclipselink entity class autoscan finds non-entities

Tags: java, orm, jpa, eclipselink

I've activated the auto-detect mode of Eclipselink 2.0 to find @Entity annotated classes:

```
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

But Eclipselink tells me that I should add an ID to my Entity:

> Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7161] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
>   Exception Description: Entity class [class com.example.domain.Image] has no primary key specified. It should define either an @Id, @EmbeddedId or an @IdClass. If you have defined PK using any of these annotations then make sure that you do not have mixed access-type (both fields and properties annotated) in your entity class hierarchy.

The example class:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

//@Entity No annotation!
public class Image extends File {

    private int width;
    private int height;
    private Set<Image> variants = new HashSet<Image>();

}
```

How can I tell Eclipselink that not @Entity annotated classes are no entities?

Comment: What version of EclipseLink?  Are you sure that Image in the compiled classes does not have the @Entity annotation?   Is File an Entity?

Comment: Good hint with "File as an Entity"! The class `File` was an entity and I commented it out for testing, but the compiled class, which was inspected by Eclipselink, was not up to date. After `mvn clean` everything works.

Answer (score 3):

The source of the problem was a compiled class which had an `@Entity` annotation before. The compiled class file still had this annotation and therefore Eclipselink considered it to be an entity. After running `maven clean` everything works as expected.